# What is the clinical description of conduction of esophageal manometry and impedance study with particular reference to supragastric belching?

Tags: gastroenterology, test, esophagus

There are patient side descriptions of these procedures. What is the clinical description of how to conduct these procedures? I live in Japan, and even in the big hospital medical suite where I am currently being treated at, I have doubts they have even heard of the procedures.

I have already had a gastroscope which the physician who conducted said was free of indications (like every other time I have been tested). What is the medical description of the esophageal manometry and impedance study?

Comment: Descriptions of how the procedure is conducted are easily found with a simple web search.

Comment: But a clinical description is much harder to find.

Comment: So you're looking for a set of instructions you can show to the Japanese doctors? The procedure is common and has been around for decades. I'd be very surprised if they don't know how to do it.

Comment: Showed the doctor a google translation of the procedures and she had never heard of them. I gave a her medical study on the procedures in English.

Comment: Wow, surprising, but now we're into personal medical advice territory so I don't think this question works here. I wish you good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Measuring esophageal manometry is a procedure measuring the strength (therefore motility and function) of the muscles relating to your swallow ability (in the esophagus). A flexible catheter is placed into your nose, which travels to your esophagus and then your stomach. You then swallow multiple times, and the data is recorded. It takes about 45 minutes to complete.

Esophageal pH impedance is a test for how much acid moves up from your stomach into your esophagus. The other end is then connected to a small device you wear for about 24 hours. This is so we can gain a good understanding of A) if acid ever comes up from the stomach into the esophagus, especially during certain normal activities.

Stomach acid should never really be 'refluxing' or moving 'up' into the esophagus, because this can injure the cells within the esophagus, especially this area called the 'z-line.'